# IIS Recycle vs ASP .NET Cache

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

does scheduled recycling an application pool affects HttpContext.Application / Cache? I can't find reference for that.I guess yes, as it causes worker process to restart, I want to make sure. I'm talking about iis 6.0 (w3wp.exe).

Thanks , Pawel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if obviously does, as the HttpContext.Application lives within the worker process that is being restarted.

Comment: Thanks. Appart from that, is there a way to send recycle events to EventLog (for instance) - I mean, I would like to trace exact moments when application is being restarted (but not using Global.asax events, rather in web.config wise way)

Answer (score 2):

Yup, recycling will restart your application and empty the cache causing it to repopulate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, so you need to fill data again as below  in Application_start event of Global.asax

```
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //load cache data
    }
</script>
```